# What is the difference between snap/beta and snap/edge in Ubuntu softwares?

Tags: 20.04, software-center, snap

In the Ubuntu software store, I found that there are three options:  `snap/stable`, `snap/beta`, `snap/edge`. So what is snap and what are the differences between those 3 options?

Answer (score 4):

These relate to [snap channels](https://snapcraft.io/docs/channels), which are broken into tracks, risks, and branches (the latter is optional). There are four risks in each track, in order of increasing stability:

- edge
- beta
- candidate
- stable

By default there is only one track ("latest"), although more can be created. For example, check out Nextcloud in the software center-- you'll see *tons* of options, all relating to the major version of Nextcloud.

In theory the difference between the beta and edge risks is that edge would be "riskier", less stable. For example, oftentimes the edge channel represents the trunk of development (e.g. every commit that lands on master ends up as a snap build in edge). In reality, this is going to vary between snaps because it all depends on how the snap developer decides to use the channels.